# How do I use recursion without using a global variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a little piece of code flatten out nested lists with multiple nests since the flatten method I found in more_itertools only seems to work with a single level of nesting. It works, but I can only get it to work by making output a global variable and having the print command outside the function.

```
nested = [[3, 4], [5, 6, 7], 8, [9, [[10, 11]]]]
output = []
def flat(items):
    for i in items:
        if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
            flat(i)
        else:
            output.append(i)



flat(nested)
print(output)
```

Comment: Sorry. That title was for a different version of the function I was going to post. The title should be better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the code a little so that the results keep appending to the previous recursive call:

```
def flat(items):
    output = []
    for i in items:
        if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
            output += flat(i)
        else:
            output.append(i)
    return output


nested = [[3, 4], [5, 6, 7], 8, [9, [[10, 11]]]]
flattened = flat(nested)
print(flattened)
```

Comment: That works. Thank you! I read that when you use recursion to maintain the state of the variable or use a global variable. When I was doing it before I kept calling 'output = []'. += flat(i) fixes that. Thx.